# jQuery logic - Infinite scroll + calling javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I am really tuck on this one, spent hours on different solutions but none works, I am really out of ideas.

So here is the thing, I am using infinite scrolling + scrollToFixed jQuery plugin to achieve 9gag like effect, and I have a function (I use WordPress) to call script in loop for every post:

```
$helper = $count - 1;
if ($count !== 1){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#sticky-'.$helper.'").scrollToFixed(
                { marginTop: 70, limit: jQuery("#item-'.$count.'").offset().top - jQuery("#sticky-'.$helper.'").height()
                }
            );
    });</script>';
};
```

Now the problem is, infinite scroll does not support  tags and they are not being called. Is there a way for me to combine those 2 things, I tried looking it up on 9gag but it's too complicated for me, I am not very good with js.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution I am now using this plugin: http://www.andersonferminiano.com/blog/2012/07/jquery-scroll-pagination/comment-page-1/#comment-690

It will include some extra coding on php side, but at least It works now!

Answer (score 0):

One of the users of ScrolledToFixed provided this demo of how to accomplish continuous scrolling with a label:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYpG/2/

Hope that helps anyone else who is looking.